# Added ' when writing formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("C18").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Raw Data'!A2"
```

When I add this to the VBA an extra ' is added around the A2, how can I fix this to not do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

ActiveCell.Formula = "='Raw Data'!A2"

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a slightly different approach:

```
Dim FormulaRng As Range

Set FormulaRng = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A2")

Range("C18").Formula = "=" & FormulaRng.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
```

**Note**: you don't need to `Select` the cell, and later on use `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1`, you can use `Range("C18").FormulaR1C1`